# How to re-install all the old SDKs(softwares) for iOS developemnt using Titanium?

Tags: titanium, ios-4.2, titanium-mobile

I'm very new to the Apple Laptop usage and iOS App development using Titanium. Currently I'm developing an iOS Application using Titanium in an Apple MacBook(Mac OS X Version 10.6.6) with the help of Titanium Developer for testing my App.

Now a days my Titanium Developer is frequently crashing in the middle of my application execution even without any error message, after gone through many threads I decided to go with Titanium Studio instead of Titanium Developer. For using this Titanium Studio I need to upgrade my Titanium SDKs and may be iOS SDKs also.

Previously all the required SDKs(Software) have been installed by one of my colleagues who started this iOS App, now I want to uninstall all the old SDKs and planing to develop the App using the new version SDKs. I'm not sure how to uninstall and install the SDKs again in Mac OS X, can anybody please help me to uninstall all the old SDKs and freshly start the iOS application development from the scratch, if possible please list down the step by step procedure for handling this scenario.

Your help is really appreciable...

Thanks in advance,
Siva

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [Titanium Studio](http://www.appcelerator.com/products/titanium-studio/), you don't need to remove all the SDKs. Titanium Studio gives the option for selecting any of your installed SDKs. For [updates](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/tis/Updating,+Changing,+Uninstalling+Studio) it shows the notifications for availability of new versions of SDKs.

Comment: yeah you're right, Titanium Studio is notifying for the updates. I already tired to update the SDKs using Titanium Studio but getting an error. Even I tried both the ways like automatic and manual(by specifying SDK URL in Help), but no use.

Comment: That's why I'm planing to start from the scratch by uninstalling all the SDKs, can you please help me to do that? Thanks for your response Muhammad Zeeshan...